# Pass native array as managed array from C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, interop

I have 3rd party lib that controls camera.
It is written in C++ and I want to consume it from C#. The lib grabs image as byte*.
There are some ways to pass this to C#.

1. Pass byte* directly to C# with unsafe statement. In this case, C# code can't change image size like crop operation.
2. Use Marshal.Copy to create managed byte array and pass it. This gives flexibility to C#, but there is overhead and additional memory usage.

So, my question is:
Is there a way to convert byte* to managed byte[] without copy? Because managed byte array with fixed statement is "blittable", I think there can be "reverse direction" method.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You have not thought enough about what you want to do in your C# code.  Pretty inevitable that you **have** to use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14(v=vs.110).aspx).  Whether you do this early or late, lots of good reasons to do it early.  Now it just doesn't matter anymore and obviously creating a managed array first is just a waste of memory and time.

Comment: When you say change an image size, what do you mean?  You can't change the size of a heap allocation which is what your byte* would typically be in C++. And in C# you can't change the size of an array. A crop operation might allocate a new smaller buffer and put the results in that. This would require an object that keeps track of a sub allocation.

Comment: @HansPassant
Oh, this is what I'm looking for...I never thought about Bitmap class's ctor. Thanks for telling me!

Comment: @tukra
Yep, we can only allocate new array to change image size. But I think if memory allocated in C++ and pass the pointer to C#, C# can't replace that pointer because it doesn't know how the pointer managed. Is this right?
</br>
Anyway, I'll try Bitmap class's ctor takes IntPtr.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1208 You can have unmanaged heap alloc/free functions that C# would use for replacing the buffer. You still need an object to hold that pointer though so when you change it the c++ code will get the new value.